# When to use defined

Tags: perl

I am a little confused as which way to test parameters. Here are two examples from source code posted below. First is this

`if(!defined($DBHdl) || !defined($acct_no));`

the way to test for undefined parameters?

Second, after assigning to a hashref

`$ptMtrRecRef = $ptSelHdl->fetchrow_hashref;`

is the best way to test for `$ptMtrRecRef` being defined to use

`if(!$ptMtrRecRef)`

or

`if(!defined($ptMtrRecRef))`?

```
###############################################################################
#  Returns count of meters per account number.

# $PkNam  -- package name discarded
# $DBHdl -- ICS database handle
# $acct_no -- water account number

sub mgbl_get_meter_count
{
    my ($PkNam, $DBHdl, $acct_no) = @_;

    die("mgbl_get_meter_count passed undef handles.\n")
        if(!defined($DBHdl) || !defined($acct_no));

    my $ptSelHdl;
    my $ptMtrRecRef;

    my $sql_statement = 
     "select count(*) from meter m where m.acct_no = ".$acct_no.";";

    $ptSelHdl = $DBHdl->prepare($sql_statement);

    die("Cannot prepare select count(*) from meter m\n")
      if(!$ptSelHdl || !$ptSelHdl->execute);

    $ptMtrRecRef = $ptSelHdl->fetchrow_hashref;

    return $ptMtrRecRef;
}
```

Comment: Turn on [`RaiseError`](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.628/DBI.pm#RaiseError) and you won't have worry about explicit error checking so much.  Use [placeholders and bind values](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.628/DBI.pm#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values) and you won't have to worry about SQL injection attacks so much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$sth->fetchrow_hashref` will either return `undef` or a reference to a hash. As such

```
if (defined($row))
```

and

```
if ($row)
```

are equivalent here. (`undef` is false, and reference is always true.) I opt for the simpler alternative.

Same idea for `$dbh->prepare`.

Answer (score 5):

In the case of the code you posted, I would also do as ikegami said, and use the shorter form.

There are occasions when that isn't suitable, however, for example if a variable could have a legitimate value that would be treated as false if simply used in a true/false test. For example:

```
my $value = 0;
print "defined\n" if defined $value;  # prints 'defined'
print "true\n" if $value;  # does not print anything
```

Answer (score 1):

Well , in perl script language, [defined($a)](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) is **just a sub routine to test if $a is "undef"**,nothing else. So ,you will ask ,what is [undef](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/undef.html)?

To be accurate, it is a perl subroutine ,the same as defined.But when it has no parameter, it can be considered as a perl-special scalar .  For example , when you pop a value from an empty array ,it will return an **undef**.When you call subroutine "undef $b",then $b will become undef($b must be an left value),nothing else. Only in this case, defined($b) will return false.But if $c is an empty string like "" ,number zero ,or string "0" ,defined($c) will still return true;

But if you use a simple boolean expression instead of defined,it becomes totally different. **A simple Boolean test will not distinguish among undef, zero, the empty string, and "0"** .So , it absolutely depends on your pratical requirement when determining using defined() or just a boolean test.